# $_FILESから画像を取り出す方法がわからない

Tags: php, objective-c

iOSアプリを開発しています。
AFNetworkingというライブラリを用いて、phpに画像をPOSTしデータベースに保存したいと思っております。

【Objective-C側】

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bird.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://kokun.sakura.ne.jp/AFNetworkingTest/addImageTest.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"tmp.png" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

【php側】

```
// 画像を受け取る
$uploaddir = 'http://kokun.sakura.ne.jp/AFNetworkingTest';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image = file_get_contents($uploadfile);

// 拡張子を取得
$ext = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// データベースに追加
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO images VALUES(0, :ext, :img)');
$stmt->bindParam(':ext', $ext);
$stmt->bindParam(':img', $image);
$stmt->execute();

// データベースサーバーからの接続を解除
$pdo=null;

// 画像の情報をJSONを返す
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_FILES);

?>
```

iOS側で返ってきたJSONを表示すると、以下のようになっておりました。

```
Success: {
    image =     {
        error = 0;
        name = "tmp.png";
        size = 13766;
        "tmp_name" = "/var/tmp/phpmRuFbC";
        type = "image/jpeg";
    };
}
```

このように$_FILESの値はきちんと表示されてます。
おそらくですが、phpにPOSTする所までは成功していているのですが、
$_FILESをうまくあつかってデータベースに接続する部分がまちがっているような気がします。

php初心者で、昨日からいろいろ試していますが解決しない状況です・・・・
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_FILE[...]['name']` に入っているのはクライアント側で指定したファイル名ですが、この名前でサーバー上に保存されるわけではありません。同じ名前のファイルを複数のクライアントが同時にアップロードしたときに困ってしまいます。

アップロードされたファイルの場所は `$_FILE[...]['tmp_name']` に格納されています。質問に書かれた例では `/var/tmp/phpmRuFbC` になっていますね。

参考 [PHP: POST メソッドによるアップロード - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ja/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
$_FILE[...]['tmp_name']をfile_get_contentsすると、
正常に画像を取り出せました！